# Toggle Selected Div of Many

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to set the background of a selected DIV using Jquery/CSS while maintaining background of other DIVs.

So say I have three DIVs with white background. I want to select DIV #3 and set background color to yellow. Then if I select #1, it will change background to yellow, and #2 and #3 will be white again.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="1" title="level" class="hover">
    <a href="#">
      1000
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="2" title="level" class="hover">
    <a href="#">
      2000
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="3" title="level" class="hover">
    <a href="#">
      3000
    </a>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hover{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px  10px 10px 6px;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
.selected{
  background-color:#F3AF4D
}
.unselected{
  background-color:#FFFFFF
}
```

**JS**

```
$('div[title="level"]').on("click", function(){

    change_background()

    $(this).toggleClass("selected");

})

function change_background(){
  $( ".hover" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "unselected" );
  });
}
```

I have something hosed as it doesn't work the way I was expecting as demonstrated in this [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/sValet/pen/rYjRgG)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS Only option using `:target` and links you your Ids

```css
.hover{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px  10px 10px 6px;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.hover:target{
  background-color:#F3AF4D
}
```

```html
  <div id="1" title="level" class="hover">
    <a href="#1">
      1000
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="2" title="level" class="hover">
    <a href="#2">
      2000
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="3" title="level" class="hover">
    <a href="#3">
      3000
    </a>
  </div>
```

Or fixing your JS

```js
$('div[title="level"]').on("click", function(){

    //Remove selected from all
    $(".hover").removeClass("selected");
    
    //Add selected to clicked item
    $(this).addClass("selected");

})
```

```css
.hover{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px  10px 10px 6px;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
.selected{
  background-color:#F3AF4D
}
.unselected{
  background-color:#FFFFFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" title="level" class="hover">
    <a href="#">
      1000
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="2" title="level" class="hover">
    <a href="#">
      2000
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="3" title="level" class="hover">
    <a href="#">
      3000
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggling a class removes it if it's present and adds the class if it is not present.  In your case with more than 2 .hover divs, you need to loop through every div and remove the 'selected' class and add the 'unselected' class.  Then finally add 'selected' to the one that was clicked on like you are doing.

```
   function change_background(){
      $( ".hover" ).each(function() {
        // remove 'selected' from every .hover
        $( this ).removeClass( "selected" ).addClass("unselected");
      });
    }
```